# Logging in as another user in Windows without resetting their password?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, password

If you own the administrator account on Windows Domain, is there a way of logging into a user account without resetting the password?  We have users that log in remotely, and I need to work on their account without resetting their password.

Comment: I know if you use Moodle if you're logged in as administrator and want to test something, you can click a users profile, and click the `login as..` button to login as the user without changing their password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't a way to login as another person without resetting or knowing their password.

Comment: Wow that sucks.  If you don't mind I'm going to wait around and see if anybody else has an answer...but in the case there isn't a way, I'll check off your answer.

Comment: Well at face value yes. However, it is a security concern if the admin can login as anyone.

Comment: Maybe Moodle should change the way they do things...

Comment: @mwjcomputing You mean "login as anyone, without generating audit events such as a password reset." :)

Comment: @jscott LOL. Yep. That is what I mean.

Comment: @mwjcomputing is correct.  There is no way but to interactively login without their password (or resetting their password).  If it's a terminal server they are accessing remotely, you can use the microsoft report support tool to access their session once they are logged in.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/330891/23300 is a similar question. You might find it informative.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 options, but I don't think it is suitable. Anyhow I explain my options.

1. Creating a scheduled task with corresponding user credentials.
2. Running a windows with corresponding user credentials.

Make both the above 2 options to perform your required work.